# Enlarge the component Name field in Tridion component creation

Tags: 2013

Enlarge view window for Content Name Field When viewing the "Name" field in Tridion, it shows a limited amount of space, whereas there may be a much larger amount of content to viewenter image description here

[image]

Comment: is it strange when I ask what exactly the question in this is? I can't really place a question mark on the end of your sentence, so I might be missing what you are really asking for.

Comment: Which solution did you go with?

Answer (score 9):

First - this isn't a description of the component. This is the name/title of the component and is used in various lists etc.

### Name

1. For naming the components I would generally recommend that you use a sense of brevity in the editor displayed name in the first place. When there are 20 of these components in a list you are going to have issues with seeing through the clutter. Additionally I would suffix the name with a 'standard format' for the schema name/type

   - xyz landing page - (article)
   - xyz marketing spot - (spot)
   - xyz marketing spot container - (spot container)
2. You could, as John says, work on a GUI extension to expand the width but

   - in this case, you're still restricted with the width of the user browser/screen
   - if you use multiline your GUI extension starts to become more complex having to deal with line breaks etc.
   - you could have an extension to simply add the full name (if the editors insist on such detail in a name) set as the 'Title' attribute so they can just hover and see the full value.
   - I see also just updating the CSS (in a supported way) would allow you to horizontally expand the width

[image]

### Using a Description

The simplest - would be to add an 'Internal Description' field as the first field of the relevant schemas. This would allow as verbose a description as you choose.

[image]

[**update**] This last approach may seem excessive at first (*this was put to me in an offline discussion*) but I've seen this to be useful where the schema concerned contained technical content - often passed in as copy and paste from another team/other teams (e.g. JSP tags, JS, CSS etc.)

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to enlarge this you could look into a GUI extension to inject some CSS to change the appearance of this text box, there's plenty of examples out there.

I'd recommend to keep these names as short as possible as the name of the item used within the WebDAV path of the item and there are limits to these paths within Windows.

Answer (score 2):

`Name` field is Self-explanatory. This field should be used for naming purpose.

**Name** — the name of the Component. Users will see this name in the folder where the component is created. Ensure that the name of the Component easily identifies. For example, "ABC Article"

You are trying to use `Name` field as either `Description/Body` content field.

Answer (score 2):

The default width of the `Name` text box is set by the the CSS of the Content Management Explorer (CME) interface.

[image]

If you are dealing with Components that have extra long names, then you could consider writing a [Bookmarklet](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324/the-tridion-bookmarklet-challenge) to update the width of this field when necessary. You may want to look at something like this [Changing pages with bookmarklets](https://www.jamestease.co.uk/blether/changing-pages-with-bookmarklets) article.

Alternatively, you could amend this within the applications CSS file, but I would advise against this, if possible.